# checkbashisms command not working

Tags: bash, debian, posix, sh

I'm trying to use [checkbashisms](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/checkbashisms.1.html) in the process of converting bash scripts to meet the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html).
I'm running the following command:

```
$checkbashisms test.sh
$
```

where test.sh is as follows:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
VAR=foo
if [ $VAR == bar ]; then
    echo 'bar!'
fi
```

As you see, I get no results. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but AFAIK the `==` should be identified as a bashism and a warning should be printed to the standard output (in this case, the command line).

Any idea why I'm not getting any warning for this bashism?

Comment: What version of checkbashisms are you using? You linked to a fairly old manpage. Could this be a newer test?

Comment: I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and then did '$sudo apt-get install devscripts'. doesn't this installs the latest version?

Comment: The latest version in a three year old Ubuntu release. Yes. But from a quick look the check is there in that version also. And the version from that package (manually extracted) seems to work on your script here.

Comment: Yes, i also checked to see the check for == is there, which it is. Thank you, i will also try to manually extract the checkbashisms and try it on other platforms.

Comment: I tried it on a debian unstable machine. You might also want to look at http://shellcheck.net . I don't know if it catches as many things but it catches this (and also catches that your unquoted `$VAR` will cause you trouble if/when `$VAR` is ever empty).

Comment: Thank you @Etan Reisner I got to work around the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to work around the problem. as suggested here by @Etan Reisner I extracted the checkbashisms file and executed it on my usual CentOS linux. It worked as expected - i received a warning about the '=='.

Comment: Did that file differ from the one you were trying before? Did the version of perl differ?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 running Perl 5.14.2 didn't work.
CentOS 6.6 running Perl 5.10.1 did work.
The same checkbashisms version was used.

Comment: Interesting. If checkbashisms has an issue tracker, IRC/XMPP room, mailing list, etc. you might want to see about trying to ask the authors about this.

Comment: Thank you @Etan Reisner, will do